# Sql where value is different from it

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry, I didn't find any answer on internet.

My postgresql query look like this :

```
SELECT distinct intervalle, inter_begin, inter_end 
FROM mytable 
WHERE inter_end != inter_begin
```

I want to select information when inter_end (timestamp) is different of inter_begin (timestamp too), because i have some result with same timestamp at the beginning and the end.
But with this query result I have the same timestamp for inter_begin and inter_end in my result and i don't want to.

So is it possible to do that? And if yes, how?

Thank you !

Comment: please add some sample data and the expected output based on the sample data. Given your query I'd say it's impossible that the result contains rows where you "*have the same timestamp for inter_begin and inter_end*"

Comment: And are you trying this directly on the server? or using some sort of Framework/adaptor that might be rounding up / coercing your data into a form with lower resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you are looking at two timestamps and they *look* the same but they are not.  For instance, if you wanted values within one second, you could change the query to:

```
SELECT distinct intervalle, inter_begin, inter_end 
FROM mytable 
WHERE ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM inter_end - inter_begin)) <= 1;
```